# Clear explanation of NMDS ordination standard deviation ellipses and confidence intervals

Tags: vegan, mds

I am looking for a clear explanation of how to correctly interpret ordination ellipses on an NMDS plot and how that interpretation changes with different user-selected confidence levels and ellipse 'kinds' (eg. standard error vs. standard deviation). Specifically I am using the `ordiellipse()` function within the `vegan` package.

For example, in my NMDS plot my data is grouped by a factor with three levels. I can plot three separate ordination ellipses using `ordiellipse()` specificying `kind='sd'` and `conf=.60` and they encompass most but not all of my points, giving me an idea of the centroid and spread of the points within each group. But I'm struggling to articulate EXACTLY what these ellipses represent. Do they mean we have 60% confidence the true mean of each group lies within its ellipse? Or that we are 60% confident that the mean + 1 Standard Deviation of each group lies within its ellipse? Or something completely different? How does this interpretation change if I alter the confidence level `conf` within `ordiellipse()`? Or the ellipse `kind` from SD to SE?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

I would comment, but I am 1 reputation away from doing so. Check Gavin Simpson's answer to this question for details on the calculation of `ordiellipse()`

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34017/confidence-intervals-around-a-centroid-with-modified-gower-similarity